# How to set constraints to an activity indicator that is not part of a tableView but below it

Tags: swift, xcode, constraints, activity-indicator

I'm not able to set constraints for an activity indicator below a tableview but not part of the table. [image]

I tried to add constraints to the activity indicator but unable to do it.
[image]

Even when I typed number, *Add Constraints* button was unable to click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want a container constraint. Your progress indicator isn't contained by your table view - they are siblings.

Tap the other button that looks like this:

[image]

And add a "spacing to nearest neighbor" constraint.